# cant emit multiple value to another component Angular

Tags: angular

i have to pass two values to my parent component

```js
@Output() onDatePicked = new EventEmitter();

public pickDate(date: any, date1: any): void {
    this.onDatePicked.emit({ date, date1 });
}
```

in my parent component:

```html
<app-child (onDatePicked)="print($event)"></app-child>
```

and in the parent controller i want log them:

```js
public print(e) {
    console.log(e.date);
    console.log(e.date1);
}
```

it logs undefined

Comment: it looks the date and date1 are already `undefined` when you emit them.

Comment: @yash if i log e it only logs date

Comment: can you try to put logs above `this.onDatePicked.emit`? both of the `date` and `date1`

Comment: You may need to share the html code too

Comment: `this.onDatePicked.emit({ date:date, date1:date1 });`, you emit an object -Are you sure that in typescript you can create an object with only the variables or is a typo error?-

Comment: @Eliseo this is a valid syntax for Typescript. The underlying values for both date and date1 are undefined is the only possible reason.

Comment: @iams0nus what do you mean?why i get the first value(first date) and not the second one?they both are coming from date  time picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Output() onDatePicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

public pickDate(date: any, date1: any): void {
    var dates = {
        date: date,
        date1: date1
    }
    this.onDatePicked.emit(dates);
}
```

Comment: when l log e.date1 i get undefiend

Comment: You can add `console.log(dates);` right before the `this.onDatePicked.emit(dates);` to see if you get the correct value of `date` and `date1`. If `date1` is `undefined` here, so you should check your input of `date1`.

Comment: i log dates and i get undefiend,its so strange

Comment: So you should check your input (in html and the method which called to `pickDate()`) to make sure you get the correct value of `date` and `date1`. In case you need more help on that, just update the question and we will try to solve it.